# Increment decrement buttons with Bootstrap and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button, bootstrap-5

How should I make this button Work?

I added this javascript line just to check but it also shows an alert without even clicking on the buttons.

```
document.querySelector(".btnminus").addEventListener(onclick,alert("hello"));
```

```
<div class="quantity d-inline-block">
<input class="btn btnminus d-inline" type="button" value="-" >
 <input type="number" class="form-control d-inline itemnumber" value="0" aria-label="Username" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
<input class="btn btnminus d-inline" type="button" value="+" >
```

Comment: You've included a version 3 Bootstrap script, which would require jQuery and has different syntax. Please update the snippet demo to use library versions that match your tags.

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

First, what is `onclick`?  The first argument to `addEventListener` is the name of the event as a string, which in this case should be `'click'`.  I suspect the only reason this isn't throwing an error is because `onclick` exists at the `window` level and, like anything, *can* be interpreted as a string.  But it's not the string you want.  The string you want is simply `'click'`.

Second, you're running the `alert` *immediately* and setting its *result* as the click handler.  And it doesn't return anything so that result is `undefined`.  Use a function for the event handler, not the *result* of a function.  (Unless the result of that function is itself a function meant to be an event handler, of course.)

Putting them together:

```
document.querySelector(".btnminus").addEventListener('click', function () {
  alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: how should I make it work that when buttons have clicked the value inside changes accordingly? also, the alert is only working on the first button but not on the second why is it so?

Comment: @kuchnahi: (1) By writting logic inside that `function` to modify the value of the `<input>` element.  There are tutorials and examples online to help you learn more JavaScript and how to do things like that.  (2) Because you're only adding an event handler to the first element matching that selector, since `querySelector` only returns one element.  [There are other methods for finding elements.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10693845/328193)